# How to select a particular node reference in a view programmatically

Tags: 6, entities, nodes, views

I have two custom node types : catalog_item and category.

The catalog_item node has a cck node reference field that allow a user to select multiple category nodes. I want to be able to select a particular category from the node reference based on some php code. Is this possible with views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the views API, you could use this field as an argument and then use PHP to supply the default argument.  This would then restrict the views to all catalog_items that have that specific category node referenced.

If you are doing this in code/a module/template/etc, you could do it also like this:

```
$nid=WHATEVERPHPCODEYOUWANT;
return views_embed_view(VIEWNAME,'default',$nid); // 'default' is the views display
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing something similar to this. Iterating through the view was pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to use one of the [views hooks](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!docs!docs.php/group/views_hooks/6).

I *believe* this will work, but I haven't tested to be sure:

```
function mymodule_views_pre_view (&$view, &$display_id, &$args)
{
  if ($view->name == "myview" && $view->current_display == "mydisplay") {
    $nid = some_function_to_get_the_nid();
    $view->args = array($nid);
  }
}
```

I don't recall if you need to set the arguments in the display handler, too.

With things like this, you need to poke through `$view` with [`dpm()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21devel%21devel.module/function/dpm/6) and experiment with the various hooks.